# Facebook shows "You" and "Me" instead of my name

Tags: facebook

I likely did something wrong when setting up my Facebook account.
When I check "Like" on a person's post, I'm listed as "You" and not by my name.
When I get an e-mail or a reply to MY post, it refers to me as "Me" and not by my name.

The Facebook name has me down as 'Me.'

How can I correct these settings?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot. I guess for you it will always so 'you' or 'me', for others it will show 'your name'.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal. You already know your name, and Facebook knows who you are, so it doesn't need to remind you of your name.

Rest assured, other people see your name. Everybody else sees "you" or "me" when they're looking at their own Likes, Posts, etc.